# Is there a bigger chance of trees dropping sapplings when breaking it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When do leaves have the biggest chance of dropping saplings: when I break the leaves or when I just break the wood and let the leaves die out?!

Comment: Dlanod can i add you as a friend or help you in any way?!

Comment: RustyMembers, @dlanod was just editing your question, to improve it - they were helping *you*. As part of the StackExchange sites, people can edit questions/answers if they think it need improvement - [the faq talks about this in more detail](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#editing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing affects the chance for sapling drops. Saplings have a chance to drop when a leaf block either decays naturally from destroying the tree, or when you manually break the leaf block yourself. Either method produces the same results with the same chance of a sapling drop.

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't matter at all.

Someone [on the Minecraft Forum](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1122673-do-leaves-drop-more-items-when-you-let-them-decay/#entry13779430) even looked at the (decompiled?) source code to confirm it.

And there's a "myth busting" episode on this topic by Xisuma: